# Am I using wxPython carbon or cocoa?

Tags: python, macos, cocoa, wxpython, macos-carbon

I have just done a fresh install of wxPython 3.0.1.1 and was trying to install the carbon version.  I installed this from the dmg labelled `wxPython3.0-osx-3.0.1.1-carbon-py2.7.dmg` and this is name that's listed when I run `uninstall_wxPython.py` that comes with the distribution, ie,

```
1.   wxPython3.0-osx.carbon-py2.7           3.0.1.1
```

None-the-less, when I list the version from within wx, it says that it's cocoa:

```
import wx
wx.version()
'3.0.1.1 osx-cocoa (classic)'
```

So something seems to be mislabeled.

My questions are: 1) which version is it, carbon or cocoa? 2) Is there a definitive way to determine whether it's cocoa or carbon from within wx, such as, by looking for some functionality that's only in either the carbon or cocoa versions, or some visual difference?

Comment: The version is 3.0.1.1. I thought I had seen something on the wxPython Google group that said the version strings aren't right, but I can't find that now.

Comment: @MikeDriscoll: sorry for the confusion, but by "version" I meant carbon or cocoa.  Is there a better term for this?  Maybe "build"?

Comment: Hmmm...not sure. I think both terms could be misinterpreted, although I know what you mean now. I would recommend asking on the wxPython Google group too or the wxpython-mac group.

Comment: The term usually used for this it "port", as in "the Cocoa port" etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue.  There was a change in the default port used for wx OSX builds but the wxPython build script wasn't using the flag to explicitly select the Carbon port so it ended up using the default Cocoa port instead but putting "carbon" in the name.  This has been fixed for the next release, which will probably happen next week during the holiday.

That said, all the current and future work in wx for OSX will be going on in the Cocoa port, so you should plan on switching to it when you can.

Comment: Thanks! And, do you know, the answer to #2... is there any way to tell the difference between the carbon and cocoa ports (aside from the labels which can get mixed up, of course)?

Comment: You can look at the tags stored in `wx.PlatformInfo` or do something like: `if "wxOSX-carbon" in wx.PlatformInfo: ...`

Comment: Great.  Thanks, Robin!  I'm looking forward to trying out the new release.